# What does Shurooq means?

Tags: practical-islam, terminology

when I used [console-mode time prayer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/itools/) for [my Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), there about was called Shurooq.

One thing that I know about it that it 's shown time before allowed to held duha prayer.  Are there another else what kind of shurooq is used to be and what does shurooq means??

Salam 
Ahmad

Comment: shuruq is an additional prayer (rather dua) offered after Fajr. This is not an obligatory prayer. There is no reason to make it obligatory. I have never heard much about this myself. [Is Sharooq obligatory?](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86157), [What time can I pray shorooq](http://www.topix.com/forum/religion/islam/T2VAQMM5F546SDCG6). I would advice to consult an Imam about this as it it is advised to follow things on your own.

Comment: I did not post this an answer because I am not an authority on this but it might help.

Comment: hi [ifoundthetruth](http://islam.stackexchange.com/users/279/ifoundthetruth), I found the answer from you link, I write it at answer. I deleted my comment cause it not related anymore. ^^

Comment: glad it could help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salamu aleykum.

Shuruq is the time when sunrise 
and it's definitely forbidden to pray at that time.

There's three times in day, 
when it's forbidden to pray:

1. at sunrise,
2. when the sun is on its highest position in the horizon
3. and at sunset.

Why? **This is** how we (muslims) **separate us from Sun worshippers.**

[like in my country, Indonesia, there are Hindus who worship like Sun worshippers]

Comment: There's no time where praying per se is forbidden, only times where it is disliked or forbidden to pray optional prayers  (See for example [Should we not pray at 12 o'clock in the night?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/should-we-not-pray-at-12-o-clock-in-the-night))

Comment: hmm,, it seem we got different acceptance in different country..

Comment: No there's mainly no difference as Allah says " Have you seen the one who forbids, A servant when he prays? "[(96:9-10)](http://legacy.quran.com/96/9-10) it is not permissible to forbid praying (by default and obligatory prayers in special) at any time, while praying an optional prayer can be forbidden, as there are times where doing so is frowned upon. The difference comes when one misunderstands only!

Answer (score 2):

Shuruq شوروق means rise of sun in the morning. One Shuruq starts then morning prayer time is finished and anyone who misses prayer till that time will perform qaza prayer.

Answer (score 1):

Shuruq is the time when the sun starts rising till it is bright, no prayer is permissible duration this period which last about 20 minutes.
If one  misses fajr prayer... which starts from subh sadiq till start of sunrise(start of shuruq) he has to offer qada of it after 20 minutes from the start of shuruq.

Answer (score 1):

Shuruq is the time when the sun starts rising till it is bright, no prayer is permissible duration this period which last about 20 minutes.
If one misses fajr prayer... which starts from subh sadiq till start of sunrise(start of shuruq) he has to offer qada of it after 20 minutes from the start of shuruq. 
Differance between sun rise or shuruq and Qaza or Nwafal of shuruq prayer is 20 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider adding references to support your answer.