# Does tahiyyet al masjid count as part of the before-fard sunnah prayers?

Tags: salat, sunnah

Al salam alaykum. I'm reading about the sunnah rakaat before fard prayers (i.e. 2+2 before and after dhur). Does tahiyyet al masjid count as part of the 2 before prayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't count as such as it is highly recommended to perform these sunnah prayers at home where one doesn't need to pray tahiyyat al-Masjid. And as tahiyyat al-Masjid has no fix timing so it is a totally separate prayer.

This means if you entered a mosque and prayed your two rak'as tahiyyat al-Masjid and have time you should perform the sunnah before dhohr prayer and wait until the dhohr prayer starts afterwards you may pray the sunnah after dhohr. But it is better to pray these sunnah prayer at home if possible.

See also [Will my salah be accepted if I pray at home?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30642/will-my-salah-be-accepted-if-i-pray-at-home)
and [Do i read the sunnah rakkats in the mosque](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34929/do-i-read-the-sunnah-rakkats-in-the-mosque/34935#34935)

Comment: Jazak Allah Khayran for your help Medi1Saif. What should I do if I don't think I'll have time to pray them after adhan at home as well as tahiyyet al masjid when I arrive? Is it better to pray them at home and go to the masjid and probably pray dhuhr straight away, or go to the masjid before adhan and pray all tahiyyet al masjid and sunnah? The ones after prayer I can do at home without problem isha2Allah.

Comment: @Khaled It depends on your time and the usual practice of the mosque. If you have not enough time to pray at home and reach the mosque at least before Iqamah you may consider pray at least the sunnah before dhohr at the mosque. Also note that there are different views on whether qada' for nafl (sunnah) prayers is valid or not and which prayers might be prayed as qada'.

Comment: Thank you @Medi1Saif. Can you also please explain what qada' is?

Comment: qada' is praying a prayer out of (after) its actual time see also [tag:salat-qada].

Comment: AFAIK, in the Hanafi school at least, praying tahiyyat al-Masjid wouldn't count as praying the the 2 rakats sunnah, but praying the 2 rakats sunnah in the masjid *would* count as praying tahiyyat al-Masjid.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I see, JAK brother.
goldPseudo That's an interesting piece of knowledge. So in the Hanafi school,  the change in the niyya to sunnah is what makes it the pre-fard sunnah as well as tahiyyat al Masjid.

Comment: What @goldPseudo mentions is also the same as in Shaf'i. _Any_ kind of prayer is enough as a salutation (i.e. tahiyyat al-Masjid).