# Can we pray kaza (missed) prayer after 12:00 am midnight?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, salat-qada

Can we pray multiple (missed) prayers after midnight if missed?

Comment: What makes you  think you may not?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge, so I may do any mistake, that's why want to be sure

Comment: I think you may find an answer in [I would like to know how to perfrom kazaa e umri](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/i-would-like-know-how-to-perform-kazaa-e-umri/) and also read [Should we not pray  at 12 o clock at nicht?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/should-we-not-pray-at-12-o-clock-in-the-night)

Answer (score 0):

You can pray missed prayer at any time instead of 11 to 12 pm and the time of sun rising when we not want to pray prayer. You can pray missed prayer after Fajar and Asar.